# Massage multiple attributes before save

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Using Rails. I have the following in a model:

```
before_save :strip_tags

private

def strip_tags
  self.name = ActionController::Base.helpers.strip_tags(self.name)
  self.description = ActionController::Base.helpers.strip_tags(self.description)
end
```

What is the better way to refactor this other than putting those attributes in an array and run a loop of them?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following which gives a whole lot more lines and changes *when* the attributes are set (you are using `before_save` so this will not work if you need the html tags in your validations).

```
def name=(string)
  write_attribute :name, strip_tags(string)
end

def description=(string)
  write_attribute :description, :strip_tags(string)
end

private

def strip_tags(string)
  ActionController::Base.helpers.strip_tags string
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'attribute_normalizer' gem:

https://github.com/mdeering/attribute_normalizer

```
normalize_attributes :name, :description do |v|
  ActionController::Base.helpers.strip_tags(v)  
end
```